# Save & load memory snapshots in JavaScript / NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory

I'm trying to save/load memory states in my app, ive been searching for this for a long time with no luck.

**What i'm trying to achieve:**
Similar to Linux Snapshots or Windows hibernation (You get it, saving the memory content to a file that can be later restored to it's original state in the VM)
Including the DOM and all window content etc.
It is highly important for the functionality of my app, and it can work in an iframe, in a Electron app (node.js)

**Closest iv'e got**:
The writeHeapSnapshot() or getHeapSnapshot() do **exactly** kind of what i need in terms of writting out a snapshot.
But i still didn't find a way to **restore** said snapshot if possible.
I'm surprised and disapointed that this isn't more common and simplier. When we can perfectly export the memory state, why not import..

Can a Node package do this? Anything? Any API? Or different approaches to get that result? I'd highly appreciate any help!!

Comment: Hey Lukas, were you able to find anything on this topic? I'm wondering as well if this is possible.